# How to echo complicated html tags

Tags: php

I need to `echo` this line,

```
<?php
echo '<input class="easyui-combobox" 
            name="language"
            data-options="
                    url:'get_clients.php',
                    method:'get',
                    valueField:'client_id',
                    textField:'client_name',
                    panelHeight:'auto'">';
?>
```

But it's showing me this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'get_clients' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\create_order.php on line 16

Comment: Hint: fix your nested quotes. Escape them.

Comment: Just write the plain html after the closing php instead of echoing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may think of using heredoc syntax to play with complex text or html:

the syntax is as follow:

```
$variableName = <<< identifier        //on one line declare var
your complex html goes here          //on a new line write your complex text
identifier;  //close identifier
```

in your case:

```
$inputElement = <<< INP
<input class="easyui-combobox" 
                name="language"
                data-options="
                        url:'get_clients.php',
                        method:'get',
                        valueField:'client_id',
                        textField:'client_name',
                        panelHeight:'auto'">
INP;

echo $inputElement ;
```

Comment: its worked as charm man thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `echo`, you can simply escape back to literal output mode of PHP:

```
<?php
if ($something) {
?>
<input class="easyui-combobox" 
        name="language"
        data-options="
                url:'get_clients.php',
                method:'get',
                valueField:'client_id',
                textField:'client_name',
                panelHeight:'auto'">

<?php }
```

Comment: this echo i have to add in an IF statement so i cant escape the php

Comment: You can do it in an `if` statement, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all single quotes using backslash(`\`), like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<input class="easyui-combobox" 
                name="language"
                data-options="
                        url:\'get_clients.php\',
                        method:\'get\',
                        valueField:\'client_id\',
                        textField:\'client_name\',
                        panelHeight:\'auto\'">';

?>
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. OR Simply don't use single quotes within the string... swap to double quotes instead (or reverse).

Comment: @josh.thomson But even with double quotes OP has to escape all the intermediary double quotes with backslash as well.

Comment: yes its working too , really thanks for help

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I said swap the inner quote type to be different to the encasing quotes. this will work, I do it all the time.